# Can not access a disposed object named "TextBox" (Leave And MouseDown Event) (How to handle System.ObjectDisposedException)

Tags: vb.net, events, exception, controls, dispose

I have a form that is build with a list of controls. However, they refresh the data in these controls by deleting them and rebuilding them. This is where it become touchy.  The error occur when i first click on another textbox which trigger the leave event from the previous textbox that call the cleaning function to rebuild all controls. The textbox clicked is include in the list of destroyed item, this is why the error "Can not access a disposed object named" occur. However, i just don't know where to handle the System.ObjectDisposedException because i cannot catch it on the form creation.

Here is the  crash log

```
 System.ObjectDisposedException: Can not access a disposed object named "TextBox".
Object name: "TextBox".
    Has System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle ()
    Has System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.CreateHandle ()
    Has System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle ()
    Has System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_CaptureInternal (Boolean value)
    Has System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseDown (Message & m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc (Message & m)
    Has System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.WndProc (Message & m)
    Has System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.WndProc (Message & m)
    Has System.Windows.Forms.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage (Message & m)
    Has System.Windows.Forms.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc (Message & m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback (IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

I also try to use the statement `if Control.Isdisposed  then return` but it's seem that the leave or mousedown event don't care about it :S

Can u guys help me to find where i can handle this error on this form particular.
I cannot trace it with debugging it just pop up after a End Sub.

**Coding in vb.net FrameWorks 1.1**

Here is my code to destroy the aimed object

```
Private Sub viderRecursiveStack(ByVal control As Control)
        Dim stack As New stack
        Dim ctl As control
        Dim enfantAssocie As ArrayList


        stack.Push(control)

        While stack.Count > 0

            ctl = CType(stack.Pop, control)


            If Not ctl Is Nothing Then

                If TypeOf ctl Is Panel Then

                    'Cree la liste des enfants associés
                    enfantAssocie = New ArrayList(ctl.Controls)

                    For Each ctli As control In enfantAssocie

                        If Not TypeOf ctli Is EasyDeal.Controls.EasyDealLabel3D AndAlso** Not TypeOf ctli Is EasyDeal.Controls.EasyDealButton Then
                            stack.Push(ctli)
                            ctl.Controls.Remove(ctli)
                        End If

                    Next

                Else
                    RemoveHandler ctl.Leave, AddressOf txtEquipAddCommissionChanged
                    ctl.Dispose()
                End If

            End If

        End While

    End Sub
```

Comment: As @SteveDog suggested you can get round this one error, but the code is going to be extremely fragile, and quite possibly dependant on windows and framework versions. If it were me I'd be trying to find another way of describing the behaviour you want.

Comment: I understand, i would like to handle my self the System.ObjectDisposedException if possible!

Comment: It is not an exception that you can handle, it is a bug in your code.  The members of the form, like "TextBox1" are referencing disposed controls.  Don't put a band-aid on it, fix the bug.  Re-running InitializeControls() ought to fix it for example.

Comment: Mr Passant is right about this one (as well :) ), at best you'll be fixing a symptom. Sniff near the code e.g add another event handler somewhere and it will just break again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you "delete" a control, you should do all of the following, and do them in this order:

1. Remove all the event handlers from the control
2. Remove the control from the control from the parent's `Controls` collection
3. Call the `Dispose` method on the control

But, in this case, you are doing all of those things, but you are still having a problem because you are trying to delete the control from its own event.  If you want to avoid getting the exception in the first place, I would recommend, in that case, waiting to call dispose on that control until a later time.  After step 2, you could add the control to a private field called `_controlsToDispose As List(Of Control)`.  Then, in the form's unload event, or on a timer, or on some other event from some other control, you could loop through any controls that have been queued up for disposal in that list and process them then.

However, if you want to leave things the way they are and just ignore the exception when it happens, you should be able to do so in your `MyApplication_UnhandledException` event handler.  To get there, open your project properties, go to the Application tab, then click the View Application Events button in the application framework frame at the bottom of the page.  This is only available if you have the application framework enabled, however.  If you have created your own entry point for your application and you are calling `Application.Run` yourself, you should be able to just put a try catch block around that call to catch it there.

Comment: I clean my control with a recursive stack correctly and removing my handler from it

Comment: So there is really no way to handle this on the form?

Comment: No.  The exception is thrown internally by framework code called by the WndProc (the window message loop).  In other words, it's processing the WM_MOUSE_DOWN message and is failing in one of Microsoft's objects because the framework assumes that the current control will not be disposed by its own event handler.

Comment: Is there any on information in the Exception that can let me know the basic of the sender event information or anything else?

Comment: Define "sender event information".  I'm not sure what you mean by that.