# Hi , I'm trying to close a form when I hit the Click Event in a ListView in vb net 2019, and I got this error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

```
Private Sub lvSuplidores_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lvSuplidores.Click
        '
        Dim ca As String
        '
        ca = lvSuplidores.FocusedItem.Text
        '
        If cotprov1 Then
            rs = cn.Execute("C_G_Suplidores_Codigo " + "'" + CStr(cta) + "', '" + CStr(ca) + "'")
            With rs
                If Not .EOF Then
                    frCotizaciones.CodPro.Text = rs.Fields("Codpro").Value
                    frCotizaciones.nompro.Text = rs.Fields("Nombpro").Value
                End If
            End With
            frCotizaciones.Comentarios.Focus()
            Me.Close()
        End If
End sub
```

==========ERROR=====================================

System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'ListView'.'

Comment: One more thing, on DoubleClick works perfect, I just want to know if is possible in one click. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi! Can you please add some more details to your question (and put the code into a code block)?

Comment: Might be helpful.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11434014/17334287

Comment: Sorry for the delay to say thank you, I had COVID last two weeks :( Thank you for your answers. I appreciated.